# HttpSession Object becoming null between sessions when using tomcat9 + Memcache

Tags: java, spring, memcached, tomcat9

We have a java web application which was hosted in tomcat 8. For session Management , we have been using the memcache which maintains non sticky based sessions. This has been working fine without any issues.

Now there is a requirement to upgrade the tomcat from 8 to tomcat 9 and the upgradation with the necessary jars for the tomcat 9 has been done. After the upgradation, we are facing an issue in the application where the session is becoming null. Some of the link in the app associated with the session are working fine and some of them when clicked gets me logged out of the session. Checking the logs, I see the session object null.

The memcached jars used as part of the tomcat 9 and copied under tomcat9/lib 
**memcache-session-manager-2.3.2
memcache-session-manager-tc9-2.3.2
jettison-1.1.jar
spymemcached-2.12.0
http-core-4.3
http-core-nio-4.3**

we are using the 3rd party Serialization for this use case and they are also copied in the tomcat lib folder

**kryo-3.0.3.jar
kryo-serializers-0.37.jar
minlog-1.3.0.jar
msm-kryo-serializer-1.9.3.jar
objenesis-2.1.jar
protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar
reflectasm-1.10.1.jar**

With these jars , I am able to see the tomcat startup without any issues.

```
 **<Manager className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager"
        memcachedNodes="n1:ip:port"
        lockingMode="auto"
        sticky="false"
        requestUriIgnorePattern= ".*\.(png|gif|jpg|css|js)$"
        sessionBackupAsync= "false"
        sessionBackupTimeout= "100"
        copyCollectionsForSerialization="false"
        transcoderFactoryClass="de.javakaffee.web.msm.serializer.kryo.KryoTranscoderFactory"/>**
```

Followed the below link for setting up the memcache configuration in my application.

https://github.com/magro/memcached-session-manager/wiki/SetupAndConfiguration

Please help  me if i am missing anything in the configuration.

Thanks
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Have solved this issue by removing the param **requesturiignore pattern ** from the context.xml as this was creating different sessions.